# How to handle a tree of URLs with a JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I had been learning Python/Django and I like their URL mapping scheme enough that I would like to use the same sort of composition in my JSF app if possible.  For example, the URL:

```
http://bjskdfu.org/stuff/aa/bb/cc
```

I would like that to be processed in the Facelets page **stuff.xhtml** where the path /aa/bb/cc is available to the page and its backing beans as a parameter.  Currently what I use is:

```
http://bjskdfu.org/stuff.xhtml?path=aa.bb.cc
```

or something like that.   Is this possible in JSF?

Comment: Not with standard JSF, but this is on schedule for OmniFaces: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/20

Comment: @BalusC is this something PrettyFaces can do?  Have you ever used it? http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Comment: No idea. I have never used it.